# Set up an NTP server to allow local machines to be synchronised for Linux

Tags: linux, ntp

I am trying to set up a machine to act as an ntp server to which the other local machines will synchronise their times to. This needs to happen regardless of whether the ntp server machine is connected to the internet, i.e: it is not important that the time is correct, just that the machines are synchronised with each other.

My configuration files are as follows:

NTP server /etc/ntp.conf

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

NTP client /etc/ntp.conf

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

server 192.168.1.146 iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

I change the time on the server
I then run the ntp server with `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start`
And try test that the client can receive an ntp update with `sudo ntpdate 192.168.1.146`

This works, but only when connected to the Internet (even though the master has the time set by my command and not from an external ntp server/s).

Anything in my configuration files wrong? Any step I am missing?

Comment: Your doesn't have anything to do with programming so it should be on Serverfault.com

Comment: I wish somebody answered that question though :(

Comment: What do you mean you set the time and not by external servers. If ntp is not adjusting the clock something is wrong. Also what was the output from ntpdate? It should have printed something. Especially if you had ntpd running when you executed that ntpdate command.

Comment: Did you have any firewall rules in place?

Answer (score 0):

When You loose connection with Internet and You don`t have resolved NTP domains in DNS cache You station can't resolve NTP domains names. Thats the first thing to check. Than You should allow this kind of transmision to get into Your stations through the firewalls if You drop all traffic and makes tunels.